# I am not fetching image from firebase while text is coming properly

Tags: android

> Here i have mention adapter class,model class & layout of my project.
>   I have doubt that glide code is proper or not which is use for fetching the image.
>   please see the following code
>   How to Check that the Glide is fetching image properly or not is there any troubleshooting for it.

```
public class MyBestDealAdapter extends
> LoopingPagerAdapter<BestDealModel> {
>         @BindView(R.id.img_best_deal)
>         ImageView img_best_deal;
>         @BindView(R.id.txt_best_deal)
         TextView txt_best_deal;
    Unbinder unbinder;

    public MyBestDealAdapter(Context context, List<BestDealModel> itemList, boolean isInfinite) {
        super(context, itemList, isInfinite);
    }

    @Override
    protected View inflateView(int viewType, ViewGroup container, int listPosition) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_best_deal_item,container,false);
    }

     @Override
        protected void bindView(View convertView, int listPosition, int viewType) {
           unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(this,convertView);

            //set data
            Glide.with(convertView).load(itemList.get(listPosition).getImage()).into(img_best_deal);
            txt_best_deal.setText(itemList.get(listPosition).getName());


        }
    }
```

> this is model class

```
public class BestDealModel {
    private String menu_id,food_id,name,image;

    public BestDealModel() {
    }

    public BestDealModel(String menu_id, String food_id, String name, String image) {
        this.menu_id = menu_id;
        this.food_id = food_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getMenu_id() {
        return menu_id;
    }

    public void setMenu_id(String menu_id) {
        this.menu_id = menu_id;
    }

    public String getFood_id() {
        return food_id;
    }

    public void setFood_id(String food_id) {
        this.food_id = food_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to me there is no any problem with your code but you can try with Picasso library also

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load(popularCategoryModelList.get(position).getImage())
               .into(holder.category_image);
                

            holder.txt_category_name.setText(popularCategoryModelList.get(position).getName());

    }I am usning glide in this but it is fetching the image